# Class Methods in Object Class of Ruby

Tags: ruby

I was trying to implement my own `attr_accessor` method. I implemented that as follow.

```
class Object
  def my_attr_accessor(*args) # self.my_attr_accessor(*args)
    args.each do |arg|
      define_method "#{arg}" do
        return instance_variable_get("@#{arg}")
      end
      define_method "#{arg}=" do |val|
        instance_variable_set("@#{arg}", val)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then I created a class which calls the `my_attr_accessor` method.

```
class Runner 
  my_attr_accessor :name
end

test= Runner.new
test.name = "runner"
puts test.name
```

My question is even though I haven't explicitly defined `self.my_attr_accessor` method, it is acting as a class method. Can someone help me in figuring out how it's happening.

**EDIT**: Irrespective of making `self.my_attr_accessor` or `my_attr_accessor` in `Object` class, it works if I say `my_attr_accessor` within my `Runner` class. Why?

Comment: Classes are objects in ruby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called "inheritance". In Ruby, subclasses "inherit" methods from their superclasses. In other words, if you send a message to an object, Ruby will look up a method whose name matches the message in the class of the object, and if it can't find it, it will follow that classes' superclass pointer, and then *that* classes' superclass pointer, and so on, until it either finds a matching method or reaches a class which doesn't have a superclass.

Since `Class` is a subclass of `Object` (indirectly via `Module`), it inherits `Object`'s methods.

[Note: inheritance is a fundamental concept in Ruby, you should probably go back and learn the fundamentals of Ruby before trying advanced reflective metaprogramming. In particular how the ancestry chain (the superclass pointers) are constructed and message dispatch works.]

Comment: I understand how inheritance works in ruby . My question is even though I have not mentioned explicitly `self.my_attr_accessor` in Object class, it behaves like a class method.
I want to understand this specific behaviour.

Comment: There is no such thing as a class method in Ruby. `Runner` is an instance of `Class`, `Class` is a subclass of `Module`, `Module` is a subclass of `Object`, `Object` has an instance method named `my_attr_accessor`, ergo, you can call `my_attr_accessor` on `Runner`, because it is inherited from `Object`. Like I said: it's just inheritance and message dispatch.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since everything is an instance of Object in ruby, you can call your method from anywhere:

```
class Object
  def my_attr_accessor(*args)
  end
end

puts self.class                           # => Object
puts self.is_a?(Object)                   # => true
puts self.respond_to?(:my_attr_accessor)  # => true

class Runner
  puts self.class                           # => Class
  puts self.is_a?(Object)                   # => true
  puts self.respond_to?(:my_attr_accessor)  # => true
  my_attr_accessor :name
end
```

Comment: I would just emphasize: Classes are Objects in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You create a new Runner with `Runner.new`. So you have an **instance** of the Runner class.
Since you called my_attr_accessor in your class block, you have created the method `.name` on your instance. This is important. `my_attr_accessor` is a call to the method my_attr_accessor. And in the base class, i.e. in Object, Ruby finds this method and calls it.
Now, you can call `test.name = "runner"`.

Comment: This answer is bit difficult to comprehend